# Javascript: Split 2D array into square regions and sum the max value of each region

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to split a matrix into square regions with the given dimensions (k) starting from the upper left corner and then sum the maximum value of each region.
This is what I've done so far.

```js
arr = [
  [ 0, 8, 1, 1, 10, 6 ],
  [ 6, 8, 7, 0, 3, 9],
  [ 0, 7, 6, 8, 6, 5],
  [ 4, 0, 2, 7, 2, 0],
  [ 4, 4, 5, 7, 5, 1]
], l = console.log, j = JSON.stringify

result = [0, 3].map(i => arr.map(a => a.slice(i, i+3)))  // map over the indexes to split by to get the parts

l(j(result ))
```

I'm not an expert in javascript but I want to learn. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: a square region is 3 * 3?

Comment: yes @NinaScholz

Comment: the given array has only 5 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your matrix in regions using `reduce()` and `forEach()` methods

```js
const arr = [
    [0, 8, 1, 1, 10, 6],
    [6, 8, 7, 0, 3, 9],
    [0, 7, 6, 8, 6, 5],
    [4, 0, 2, 7, 2, 0],
    [4, 4, 5, 7, 5, 1]
  ], l = console.log, j = JSON.stringify

function splitMatrix(data, n) {
  let row = 0;
  return data.reduce(function(r, a, i) {
    if (i && i % n == 0) row++;
    let col = 0;
    a.forEach(function(e, j) {
      if (j && j % n == 0) col++;
      if (!r[row]) r[row] = [];
      if (!r[row][col]) r[row][col] = [];
      r[row][col].push(e)
    })
    return r;
  }, [])
}

const s = splitMatrix(arr, 3);
console.log(j(s))
```

And to get maximum value of each region you could do that inside foreach loop and then use `reduce()` to sum those values.

```js
const arr = [
    [0, 8, 1, 1, 10, 6],
    [6, 8, 7, 0, 3, 9],
    [0, 7, 6, 8, 6, 5],
    [4, 0, 2, 7, 2, 0],
    [4, 4, 5, 7, 5, 1]
  ], l = console.log, j = JSON.stringify

function splitMatrix(data, n) {
  let row = 0;
  return data.reduce(function(r, a, i) {
    if (i && i % n == 0) row++;
    let col = 0;
    a.forEach(function(e, j) {
      if (j && j % n == 0) col++;
      if (!r[row]) r[row] = [];
      if (!r[row][col]) r[row][col] = [e];
      if (r[row][col][0] < e) r[row][col][0] = e;
    })
    return r;
  }, [])
}

const max = splitMatrix(arr, 3)
const result = [].concat(...max).reduce((r, [e]) => r + e, 0);
console.log(j(max))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: it should be 3*3 matrix, not 0-3 matrix as OP said, so the count of the 3*3 child matrix of 6*5 should be 4*3=12.

Answer (score 2):

I know it bit complex but it is working. It will try to get a region what you want, but it will take whatever left if a region of specific size is not possible.(in our case, it will divide array in 2 region of 3*3, and another 2 region of 2*3)(Warning:- it will not work if all element in region is less than -100, if you want that it work please change value of 'runningMax' accordingly)

```js
function max(arr){
  var runningMax=-100;
 for(i = 0, i2 = arr.length; i<i2; i++) {
      runningMax = Math.max.apply(null, arr[i].concat(runningMax));
  }
  return runningMax;
}

arr = [
  [ 0, 8, 1, 1, 10, 6 ],
  [ 6, 8, 7, 0, 3, 9],
  [ 0, 7, 6, 8, 6, 5],
  [ 4, 0, 2, 7, 2, 0],
  [ 4, 4, 5, 7, 5, 1]
], l = console.log, j = JSON.stringify

result = [0, 3].map(i => arr.map(a => a.slice(i, i+3)));

y=[0,3].map(i=>result.map(a=>a.slice(i,i+3)));

var v=0;
y.forEach(function(e){
 e.forEach(function(q){
  //console.log(max(q) + "  "+ q);
  v+=max(q);
 })
});

console.log(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    
const arr = [
  [ 0, 8, 1, 1, 10, 6 ],
  [ 6, 8, 7, 0, 3, 9],
  [ 0, 7, 6, 8, 6, 5],
  [ 4, 0, 2, 7, 2, 0],
  [ 4, 4, 5, 7, 5, 1]
];

const sizeX = 3, sizeY = 3;

// Go over the different squares
for(let minX = 0; minX < arr.length - sizeX; minX++){
  for(let minY = 0; minY < arr[0].length - sizeY; minY++){
     // Sum their content up
     var sum = 0;
     for(let x = minX; x < minX + sizeX; x++)
        for(let y = minY; y < minY + sizeY;  y++)
            sum += arr[x][y];
      // Do whatever with the sum
      console.log(sum)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the array is 6x5, so you couldn't split it evenly into square regions. That's a little besides the point though. If you want to go through the whole thing, the first step is to have a function that can take a certain chunk of a matrix and sum it up.

Let's say we have an matrix, and we want to make a function that takes an x, y, width and height for what we want to sum up.

```js
const m = [
 [1,2,3,4,5],
 [2,3,4,5,6],
 [3,4,5,6,7],
 [8,9,10,11,12]
];

const sumArea = (m, x, y, w, h) => {
  let sum = 0;
  
  if (y + h > m.length) {
    throw new Error('Matrix is not tall enough for the requested area');
  }
  
  if (x + w > m[0].length) {
    throw new Error('Matrix is not wide enough for the request area');
  }
  
  for (let j = y; j < y + h; j++) {
    for (let i = x; i < x + w; i++) {
      sum += m[j][i];
    }
  }
  
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumArea(m, 0, 0, 3, 3));
```

With this, we can loop through an arbitrary area of a matrix and sum up everything in it. To do that, we just use a `for` loop from the starting point (`x` and `y`) to the end (`x + width`, `y + height`).

I added a check if the area goes out of bounds and throw an error. You could alternately just count those as zero and skip them (by adding some conditions in your `for` loop.

After that, to square all of them, you'd just iterate over each bit.

```js
const m = [
 [1,2,3,4],
 [2,3,4,5],
 [3,4,5,6],
 [8,9,10,11]
];

const sumArea = (m, x, y, w, h) => {
  let sum = 0;
  
  if (y + h > m.length) {
    throw new Error('Matrix is not tall enough for the requested area');
  }
  
  if (x + w > m[0].length) {
    throw new Error('Matrix is not wide enough for the request area');
  }
  
  for (let j = y; j < y + h; j++) {
    for (let i = x; i < x + w; i++) {
      sum += m[j][i];
    }
  }
  
  return sum;
}

const sumSquares = (m, w, h) => {
  let result = [];
  
  for (let y = 0; y < m.length / h; y++) {
    result[y] = [];
    
    for (let x = 0; x < m[0].length / w; x++) {
      result[y][x] = sumArea(m, x * w, y * h, w, h);
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(sumSquares(m, 2, 2));
```

For this, we loop through each square that we'll have. The number of squares we'll have is the size of the matrix divided by the width of the square (so, a matrix that is 4x4, with 2x2 squares would have 2 across and 2 down). Then I just put those into another matrix to show their total size.

Answer (score 0):

With a same length and height array, you could iterate the arrays and take the indices for the group for counting.

```js
var array = [[0, 8, 1, 1, 10, 6], [6, 8, 7, 0, 3, 9], [0, 7, 6, 8, 6, 5], [4, 0, 2, 7, 2, 0], [4, 4, 5, 7, 5, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
    result = array.reduce((r, a, i) => {
        a.forEach((b, j) => {
            r[Math.floor(i / 3)] = r[Math.floor(i / 3)] || [];
            r[Math.floor(i / 3)][Math.floor(j / 3)] = (r[Math.floor(i / 3)][Math.floor(j / 3)] || 0) + b;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to look at all possible 3x3 sub-matrices of the given matrix. So I assume that in your example matrix you want to look at:

```
[ 0, 8, 1 ]    [ 8, 1, 1 ]    [ 1, 1, 10]    [ 1, 10, 6 ]
[ 6, 8, 7 ]    [ 8, 7, 0 ]    [ 7, 0, 3 ]    [ 0, 3,  9 ]
[ 0, 7, 6 ]    [ 7, 6, 8 ]    [ 6, 8, 6 ]    [ 8, 6,  5 ]

[ 6, 8, 7 ]    [ 8, 7, 0 ]    [ 7, 0, 3 ]    [ 0, 3, 9 ]
[ 0, 7, 6 ]    [ 7, 6, 8 ]    [ 6, 8, 6 ]    [ 8, 6, 5 ]
[ 4, 0, 2 ]    [ 0, 2, 7 ]    [ 2, 7, 2 ]    [ 7, 2, 0 ]

[ 0, 7, 6 ]    [ 7, 6, 8 ]    [ 6, 8, 6 ]    [ 8, 6, 5]
[ 4, 0, 2 ]    [ 0, 2, 7 ]    [ 2, 7, 2 ]    [ 7, 2, 0]
[ 4, 4, 5 ]    [ 4, 5, 7 ]    [ 5, 7, 5 ]    [ 7, 5, 1]
```

Then I understand you want to find the maxima (12 maxima for 12 matrices):

```
8    8   10   10

8    8    8    9

7    8    8    8
```

The sum of these is 100. So if that is indeed the outcome you want to have, here is a functional way to get it:

```js
const arr = [
  [ 0, 8, 1, 1, 10, 6 ],
  [ 6, 8, 7, 0, 3, 9],
  [ 0, 7, 6, 8, 6, 5],
  [ 4, 0, 2, 7, 2, 0],
  [ 4, 4, 5, 7, 5, 1]
];

const sum = arr.slice(2).reduce( 
    (sum, row, i) => row.slice(2).reduce( 
        (sum, a, j) => sum + Math.max(...arr[i].slice(j,j+3), 
                                      ...arr[i+1].slice(j,j+3), 
                                      ...row.slice(j,j+3)),
        sum
    ), 0
)

console.log(sum);
```